# MATLAB sound generation with increased dB-value

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing

This may look like an easy question for some of you, but I'm not very familiar with signal processing, and I'd rather be sure about this.

So I've found some easy code to generate a pure tone in MATLAB:

```
Fs = 44100;
duration = 5.0;

numberOfSamples = Fs * duration;
samples = (1:numberOfSamples) / Fs;
s = sin(2 * pi * freq * samples);

sound(s, Fs);
```

I'd like to be able to adjust the volume in terms of dB here. More precisely, I want to introduce a certain parameter, say `dbOffset`, which, after calibration, determines how loud the tone is.

For example: if I calibrate so that `dbOffset = 0` results in a tone of 50 dB, I want `dbOffset = 10` to result in 60 dB, and so on.

Is this possible? Could anyone please help me with this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably all that you need to know is that 20 dB is equal to a factor of 10, i.e.

```
dB = 20 * log10(V / V0)
```

So to increase the amplitude by 20 dB your peak value needs to go up by a factor of 10, and conversely -20 dB is a reduction in amplitude by a factor of 10.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed is what I need to know! So to add `k*10` dB, I need to multiply the amplitude by `sqrt(10) ^ k`.

Comment: Yes - I think that's right. E.g. 60 dB is a factor of 1000, so k = 6 => sqrt(10)^6 = 3.16227766016838^6 = 1000.

Answer (score 4):

The intensity of the sound (i.e. how loud it is) is determined by the amplitude of the sound wave. To increase or decrease the amplitude of a sine, you have to multiply it by a scale factor. Generally speaking:

```
 A*sin(2*pi*f)
```

yields a sine wave with a peak value (and therefore amplitude) of **A**, and frequency of **f** Hz. That, of course, in the continuous world.

That said, to control the sound intensity you have to multiply it by some constant.

Then, you have to look how the `sound` function works. From the official documentation:

> The sound function assumes that y contains floating-point numbers between -1 and 1, and clips values outside that range.

That loosely translates to: if the amplitude y is equal to one, the soundcard will emit the loudest sound it can. Oops, there you face a problem: the actual sound intensity is mainly dependent on the sound card and the loudspeakers connected to the PC... So it's not that easy to make a generic function that spits out some sound in decibels...

If you want just to play with the concept, and get used to it, try:

```
Fs = 44100;
duration = 2.0;

numberOfSamples = Fs * duration;
samples = (1:numberOfSamples) / Fs;
s = sin(2 * pi * freq * samples);
s2 = 0.5*sin(2*pi*freq*samples);

sound(s, Fs);
sound(s2,Fs);
```

This will create a sound with a peak value that's half the peak value of the first one played. That **does not** mean that it has half the intensity, or, using better terms, the power. The power of a sinusoid is not linearly related to its amplitude, but that's a completely different story.

Bottom line is: to do what you want, you'll have to know the whole system involved in reproducing the sound, you'll have to know some physics to calculate the power, and then, just then, you'll be able to write some code that, multiplying the sinusoid by some calculated constant, plays a sound wave with a specified intensity :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So actually I should work the other way around: put the hardware volume up to a maximum, say 130 dB, and let the amplitude of that volume correspond to 1. Starting from this, is there a way to divide this amplitude and be sure it will correspond with a certain dB-value? I have a feeling it can't be that hard from here.

Comment: Yep, there is. But I already gave you all the hints you need so that you can figure that out yourself ;)