# Converting Power Spectrum to decibel

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, decibel

I was able to display an acoustic data in Matlab using Signal Anaysis tool box but I have little challenge in converting that into dB. I'm really new to this kind of processing. 
Is there someone you can help with please? I also intend to remove 58 dB from the resulting signal. 
I have the data with me and I can attach it if that might help.
Thanks

Comment: Please show what have you done so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MATLAB sound generation with increased dB-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013627/matlab-sound-generation-with-increased-db-value)

Answer (score 3):

dB is a *ratio*, not an absolute value. Typically you might express something as dB relative to some reference, e.g. "dB re full scale", or "dB re 1V". The dB value is calculated as:

```
db = 20 * log10 ( V / V0 )
```

where `V0` is the reference and `V` is the value of interest.

Using the above value, your requirement to "remove 58 dB" translates to multiplying your current values by `10 ^ -(58 / 20)` = `0.001259`.